# Bazel: java_library character encoding via javacopts not working?

Tags: character-encoding, javac, iso-8859-1, bazel

I have an external source repository that apparently stores some source files using ISO-8859-1 character encoding. I am having trouble getting javac to change from default UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 when invoked through Bazel.

I'm fetching the external repository via Bazel and can determine the charset of the fetched files:

```
> cd bazel-PROJECT/external/third-party/src
> file -i LibraryCode.java 
LibraryCode.java: text/x-c; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Building the external sources via Bazel's java_library, or attempting to compile external repository source files via javac directly from the command line fails with (expected):

```
error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8
```

Attempting to use javac's -encoding argument solves the compilation issue when used from the command line against the external repository files fetched by Bazel:

```
> javac -encoding iso-8859-1 LibraryCode.java
```

However, I've been unable to successfully pass the -encoding option to javac via Bazel.

I've tried so far:

1. setting the javacopts in java_library rule
2. setting --javacopt from Bazel's command line
3. declaring java_toolchain rule with encoding ISO-8859-1 and using it with --java_toolchain from Bazel's command line.

None of these attempts got around the charset mismatch and compiler error.

1) repository_rule build_file: thirdparty.BUILD

```
java_library(
  name = "thirdparty",
  srcs = glob(["src/**/*.java"]),
  javacopts = ["-encoding iso-8859-1"],
  visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)
```

2) Bazel command line:

```
> bazel build --javacopt="-encoding iso-8859-1" target
```

3) Defining Java toolchain target with encoding setting:

```
java_toolchain(
  name = "toolchain",
  bootclasspath = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:bootclasspath"],
  encoding = "iso-8859-1",
  extclasspath = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:extdir"],
  forcibly_disable_header_compilation = 0,
  genclass = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:GenClass_deploy.jar"],
  header_compiler = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:turbine_deploy.jar"],
  ijar = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:ijar"],
  javabuilder = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:JavaBuilder_deploy.jar"],
  javac = ["@bazel_tools//third_party/java/jdk/langtools:javac_jar"],
  javac_supports_workers = 1,
  jvm_opts = [
    "-XX:+TieredCompilation",
    "-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1",
  ],
  misc = [
    "-XDskipDuplicateBridges=true",
  ],
  singlejar = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:SingleJar_deploy.jar"],
  source_version = "8",
  target_version = "8",

  visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)
```

All end up with error: unmappable character for encoding UTF8.

What is the mistake I am making in setting the javac encoding via Bazel?

I can try to work around the issue by converting the external repository source files via iconv but I'd prefer solving it via javac's encoding setting as intended.

## Follow Up

The java_toolchain encoding not getting recognized appears to be a bug. I've a preliminary fix for this on my local copy of Bazel -- java_toolchain approach to changing charset (option #3 above) appears to work.

Tracking this issue and a proposed fix in: [#2926](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2926)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no good way to do that from the command line / target based. You have to write a [java_toolchain](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/be/java.html#java_toolchain) and point to it. Deriving the [one from bazel](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/8df71b5df115df8ed9af196b72ab36683d18c988/tools/jdk/BUILD#L136) that would result in:

```
java_toolchain(
    name = "toolchain",
    bootclasspath = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:bootclasspath"],
    encoding = "iso-8859-1",
    extclasspath = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:extclasspath"],
    forcibly_disable_header_compilation = 0,
    genclass = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:genclass"],
    header_compiler = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:turbine"],
    ijar = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:ijar"],
    javabuilder = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:javabuilder"],
    javac = ["@bazel_tools//third_party/java/jdk/langtools:javac_jar"],
    javac_supports_workers = 1,
    jvm_opts = [
        "-XX:+TieredCompilation",
        "-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1",
    ],
    misc = [
        "-XDskipDuplicateBridges=true",
    ],
    singlejar = ["@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:SingleJar_deploy.jar"],
    source_version = "8",
    target_version = "8",
)
```

(you might want to change the singlejar target to the C++ binary for performance reason: `@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:singlejar` IIRC)

Then you can point to that toolchain with `--java_toolchain=//my:toolchain` (see the [java_toolchain flag](https://bazel.build/versions/master/docs/bazel-user-manual.html#flag--java_toolchain))

Comment: Thanks for your response.

I had attempted to use the toolchain definition earlier but with no success. I now tried again, and still wasn't able to work past the issue.

I am out of ideas for the moment short of trying to inspect the source code to see what might be going wrong.

Comment: Is there a repository I could look at to see if we can make your use case work?

Comment: I'll see what I can set up (legacy repo is in svn and I've custom extension for svn repository_rule).

In the meanwhile, I played with java_common.compile() and managed to get an exception stack trace out of it, with illegal argument exception from sun.* package when used with -encoding option. I suspect the root cause may be here: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/3c5e55ff8e058b624ce26e803ff00434c70d4b91 which also raised the bug here: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2606

In short, the Sun Javac API getTask() only accepts options in BASIC group, excluding all else.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer. The toolchain configuration with encoding will solve this, once [issue #2926](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2926) with the proposed fix (or an equivalent solution) has been released.